# using the github api, from a commit sha can i tell how many commits occur after it

Tags: github-api

If i have a commit sha like this:

```
435a4b8c99ae739316af1bf5db9fcc8b0cd104ef
(from https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook)
```

as of this writting the commit is "third latest", how can i arrive at this count this using the API?
is there another way other than calling :

```
 curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/GitbookIO/gitbook/commits
```

and counting the sha's position in the reply?

Comment: You could do a compare between that commit and the latest commit: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits. Notice that there's a "total_commits" field in the response.

Comment: @IvanZuzak that works quite well, would you like to convert that to an answer?  another thing, do you think its possible for an application that does text editing to emulate git using the git api purely without ever shelling  out to git (or cloning a repo?) i.e. things like fetching a file (possible via api), modifying and sending the modified file back (possible via api), what i wonder is if its changed on github after orignally  getting the file, how would i reconcile any local change and whats on github without using git in the shell (only use API)

Comment: Sure thing, added it as an answer. About your other question -- yeah, I guess that would be possible. For example, the Repo Contents API lets you read/write files in repositories: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/. Notice that the API to update a file also takes a SHA of the file being updated: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file. So, if you try updating a file but supply a different SHA from what's on the server - the API will fail and let you know that something is not in sync. Feel free to contact us at support@github.com if you'd like to talk more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a compare between that commit and the latest commit:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits

Notice that there's a `total_commits` field in the response.